# How to use my registry configurations in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator in a Message Processor

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm working with WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0. I have a file `usage-service-config` in my app the file is below

[image: Navigation Image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="usage-service-config" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <configuration xmlns="http://config.usageService.gravity.hp.com">
        <!-- Local End Points -->
        <dss_ep>https://localhost:8243/services/ds</dss_ep>
        <api>https://localhost:8243/usage</api>
        <api_ep>https://localhost:8243/api</api_ep>
    </configuration>
</localEntry>
```

I want to use one of the values stored in the above file in an endpoint while calling the endpoint through a [Message Processor](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Message+Processors+)

How can I achieve this?

Here is the flow of my App :

**Sequence:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="usageService-get-processDcsCustomers-seq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property description="Get Configuration" expression="get-property('registry','conf:/usage-service/usage-service-config.xml')" name="usage-service-config" scope="default" type="OM"/>
    <property description="Get DSS Endpoint" expression="$ctx:usage-service-config//n0:usageService_dss_ep/text()" name="uri.var.usageService_dss_ep" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:n0="http://config.usageService.gravity.hp.com"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint key="some-data-ep"/>
    </call>
    <log level="full"/>
    <foreach expression="//gravity:allCustomers/gravity:customers" id="allCustomers" xmlns:gravity="some-ds">
        <sequence>
            <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <store messageStore="my-ms"/>
        </sequence>
    </foreach>
</sequence>
```

**Message Store:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageStore class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.memory.InMemoryStore" name="my-ms" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
```

**Message Processor:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageProcessor class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" messageStore="my-ms" name="my-mp" targetEndpoint="my-ep" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="client.retry.interval">1000</parameter>
    <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">1</parameter>
    <parameter name="member.count">1</parameter>
    <parameter name="non.retry.status.codes">400</parameter>
    <parameter name="max.delivery.drop">Enabled</parameter>
    <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
    <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="target.endpoint">my-ep</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

**Endpoint:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="my-ep" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="post" uri-template="https://localhost:8243/api/abc"/>
</endpoint>
```

**API:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/api" name="my-api" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="pOST" protocol="https" uri-template="/health">
        <inSequence>
            <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
            <sequence key="my-seq"/>
            <loopback/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

How can I use the values of the config file to call the endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was able to do overcome this by getting my registry configurations in the **sequence** where I'm storing the data in **Message Store**. and then used the same property in the Endpoint that I was calling from **Message Store**

**Sequence**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="usageService-get-processDcsCustomers-seq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property description="Get Configuration" expression="get-property('registry','conf:/usage-service/usage-service-config.xml')" name="usage-service-config" scope="default" type="OM"/>
    <property description="Get DSS Endpoint" expression="$ctx:usage-service-config//n0:usageService_dss_ep/text()" name="uri.var.usageService_dss_ep" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:n0="http://config.usageService.gravity.hp.com"/>
    <property description="Get API Endpiont" expression="$ctx:usage-service-config//n0:api_ep/text()" name="uri.var.link" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:n0="http://config.usageService.gravity.hp.com"/>
    <call>
        <endpoint key="some-data-ep"/>
    </call>
    <log level="full"/>
    <foreach expression="//gravity:allCustomers/gravity:customers" id="allCustomers" xmlns:gravity="some-ds">
        <sequence>
            <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <store messageStore="my-ms"/>
        </sequence>
    </foreach>
</sequence>
```

**Endpoint**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="my-ep" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.link}/abc"/>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use one of the values stored in the above file in an endpoint while calling the endpoint through a Message Processor

The message processor itself may have only a single static value configured. Still you may create a proxy service or api, where you can read the value from the registry and the call the configured endpoint.

If you want to dynamically change the target endpoint, you can change the `To` header.

```
<property name="xmlvalue" expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/xml/body.xml')" type="OM" /
<header name="To" expression="$ctx:xmlvalue//api_ep" />
<!-- send or call ->
```